# How to set VirtualBox to the new path of the file?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

So I have installed Oracle VM VirtualBox.
I have a VirtualBox that I had to move to another folder because my disk was already full. So I moved the entire VirtualBox VM's folder.
The problem is Oracle can't find the Virtual Machine anymore. It says:

```
Runtime error opening 'C:\Users\jpedr\VirtualBox VMs\ECOMP\ECOMP.vbox' for reading: -103 (Path not found.).
```

which does not surprise has the path indeed changed. How do I tell VirtualBox the correct path to look for the Machine?

EDIT:
I already went to VirtualBox Preferences and changed the default folder. It still looks for the machine in the old one.

Answer (score 1):

1.backup the original  vm folders (VirtualBox VMs\ECOMP)

2.create a new os with previous file name (ECOMP)

3.boot the new os with old virtual hard disk (C:\Users\jpedr\VirtualBox VMs\ECOMP\ECOMP.vbox)

4.shutdown the os

5.replace the new os folder files with old os files

6.start the new os

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the VirtualBox config file under C:\Users\jpedr.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml

1. Close VirtualBox
2. Open the VirtualBox.xml file
3. Search for MachineRegistry entry
4. Set the correct path
5. Start VirtualBox